# How to get the member's server nickname discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to get the member's nickname from a certain server which i chose.
Not the server the command is sent in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your bot needs to be in the guild you want to get the nickname from.
2. You then can fetch/get the guild using:
   `guild = await client.fetch_guild(guild_id)`
3. Then you can fetch the member from that guild using:
   `member = await guild.fetch_member(member_id)`
4. Using the nick attribute you can return the nick.
   `print(member.nick)`