# discord.py fetch_message message object doesn't include nick

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I've been writing a Discord bot.
I wanted to detect when a message is a reply to an older message and access the Message object of the older message so i wrote the following code inside the on_message event.

```
if message.reference:
        refid = message.reference.message_id
        refinfo = await channel.fetch_message(refid)
        print(refinfo)
        refauthor = refinfo.author
        refauthorname = refauthor.name
        refauthorid = refauthor.id
        refauthorbot = refauthor.bot
```

The code works fine. The problem is that the Message object returned through fetch_message doesn't include the nick attribute like a normal Message Object does:

Normal Message Object printed:
**nick='Orfy'**

```
<Message id=999585075660345434 channel=<TextChannel id=893561314331471872 name='testrelay' position=6 nsfw=False news=False category_id=967373713337118750> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<Member id=12345678901234 name='Orfeas' discriminator='xxxx' bot=False nick='Orfy' guild=<Guild id=12345678901234 name='ORF' shard_id=None chunked=False member_count=7>> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

Message Object from fetch_message:

```
<Message id=999584917153386526 channel=<TextChannel id=893561314331471872 name='testrelay' position=6 nsfw=False news=False category_id=967373713337118750> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=12345678901234 name='Orfeas' discriminator='xxxx' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>
```

Am i doing something wrong or is this default behavior?

Thx in advance.

P.S i replaced some id's on the prints with fake ones

Comment: Well, one is type `Member` and the other is type `User`. Users don't have nicknames.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs ah, i see. Thanks! I suppose a solution would be to just use the user id and [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71616987/19592609) steps to get the nickname?

Comment: Indeed, but I would advise against using `fetch_member/guild` as both make an API call for no reason. Instead, simply use `get_member/guild`

Comment: Thanks a lot! :) I made it work with get_member!